# No entiendo el porque no funcionaría este programa en C

Tags: array, c

He hecho un programa en `C`, de un array dinámico, en el cuál yo introduzco el tamaño de dicho array, visualizo los números que he introducido y después visualizo los números ordenados empleando el método de ***Bubble Sort***. 
Pongo aquí el código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int introducir_tam (void);
int *dimensionar (int );
void introducir(int, int*);
void visualizar(int, int*);
void ordenar(int, int *);

int main()
{
    int *t;
    int tam;
    tam=introducir_tam();
    t=dimensionar (tam);
    introducir (tam,t);
    printf ("\n\n");
    visualizar (tam,t);
    ordenar(tam, t);
    printf ("\n\n");
    visualizar (tam,t);
    free(t);
    return 0;
}

int introducir_tam (void)
{
    int tam;
    printf ("Introducir tamano del ARRAY: ");
    scanf ("%d",&tam);
    return tam;
}

int *dimensionar (int tam) //Pasar también t
{
    int *t;
    return t=(int *)malloc(tam*sizeof(int));
}

void introducir(int tam, int *t)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<tam;i++)
    {
        printf ("Ingrese elemento: ");
        scanf("%d",t+i);
    }
}

void visualizar(int tam, int *t)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<tam;i++)
        printf ("%d\t",*(t+i));
}

void ordenar(int tam, int *t)
{
    int i, j, aux;
    for (i=0; i<=tam-2; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<=tam-2-i; j++)
        {
            if(t[j] > t[j+1])
            {
                aux = t[j];
                t[j] = t[j+1];
                t[j+1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hasta aquí todo perfecto. Pero mi profesor me dijo cambia en el **main**, en vez de `t=dimensionar (tam);`prueba llamar la función pero pasando tanto el tamaño **(tam)**, como el array **(t),** quedando asi: `dimensionar (tam, t);.`

Me dijo de que eso no iba a funcionar, pero que entendiese el porqué y le he dado vueltas y no se porqué *crashea* el programa cuando voy a introducir el primer índice del array. Estoy empezando con `C` y no me entero muy bien de ciertas cosas.

Comment: `No entiendo el porqué no funcionaría este programa ...`. A ver si me aclaro: el código que muestras ... ¿ funciona o no funciona ? Si funciona, ¿ qué estás preguntando ? Si no funciona ... ¿ Qué problema tienes ? Algún error de compilación, de funcionamiento, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que te dice tu profesor es que intentes esto otro:

```
void dimensionar(int tam, int *t) {
    t=(int *)malloc(tam*sizeof(int));
}
```

Como ves en este caso la función no retorna el valor del puntero, sino que directamente intenta asignar el resultado del `malloc()` al parámetro `t` que recibe. Por tanto la forma de llamarlo desde el programa principal sería:

```
int *t;
int tam;
tam=introducir_tam();
dimensionar(tam, t);
```

Esto no funcionará porque la función dimensionar trabaja con una copia de `t` y no con la misma variable `t` de `main()`.  Quizás sea más fácil de entender si le das un nombre diferente, y un valor inicial en el `main()`, así:

```
int *tt = NULL;
int tam;
tam=introducir_tam();
dimensionar(tam, tt);
```

En este caso, `main()` tiene una variable llamada `tt` que vale `NULL`. Cuando se invoca `dimensionar()` ésta crea otra variable llamada `t` para su parámetro y copia en él el valor que recibe desde `main()`, por lo que `t` valdrá inicialmente también `NULL`. Después `dimensionar()` hace un `malloc()` y asigna el resultado a `t`, la cual dejará entonces de valer `NULL`, tras lo cual retorna.

El problema es que `tt` seguirá valiendo `NULL`, puesto que quien fue asignada fue su copia `t`. A partir de ahi, cuando `main()` intente usar `tt` para cualquier cosa, el programa romperá.

Si hubiéramos querido que funcione de esta forma, tendríamos que haber hecho:

```
void dimensionar(int tam, int **t) {
    *t=(int *)malloc(tam*sizeof(int));
}
```

y desde `main()`:

```
int *t = NULL;
int tam;
tam=introducir_tam();
dimensionar(tam, &t);
```

Esto es un poco más difícil de explicar. `main()` empieza como antes, haciendo un puntero `tt` inicializado con `NULL`, pero ahora, cuando llamas a `dimensionar`, en lugar de pasarle el valor del puntero (`NULL`) le pasas *la dirección de memoria en que está el puntero*. Digamos que es, por ejemplo `0xA000B000`.

La función `dimensionar()` crea una variable local llamada `t` y le asigna el valor que ha recibido desde `main()`, es decir, le asigna `0xA000B000`. Fíjate que ahora el tipo de `t` es "puntero a puntero". Esto significa que `t` apunta a una dirección de memoria donde hay un puntero. Efectivamente, así es, ya que en la dirección de memoria apuntada por `t` está el puntero  `tt`.

Cuando después se llama a `malloc()`, el resultado de éste se asigna a `*t`. El uso del asterisco delante de `t` hace que ese valor no se copie en `t`, sino en la dirección apuntada por `t`. Allí había un `NULL` (pues ese era el valor de `tt`) y se cambiará por lo que `malloc()` retorne. Como consecuencia *hemos cambiado el valor de `tt`* desde dentro de la función.

Cuando la función retorne, la variable `tt` de `main()` ya no es `NULL` sino que apuntará a la zona reservada. El uso de `tt` para acceder a esa zona ya no producirá errores.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que explicas no tiene mucho sentido, porque el puntero al array lo obtienes en el *malloc*.

El valor que pases por parámetro no sirve de nada, ya que se guarda en una variable local de *dimensionar()* que dejará de existir tan pronto salgas del métodos; no te sirver para pasar el valor del *malloc* de vuelta al método principal.

Una opción sería usar *un puntero a puntero* o una *refencia a puntero*, de forma que con el valor *t* apuntes a una variable externa a *dimensionar()* (por ejemplo, variable en el heap o variable local en el método que llama a dimensionar). P. ej.

```
// Variable local
int tam;
tam=introducir_tam();
int *t;
dimensionar(tam, &t);

// Variable heap
int tam;
tam=introducir_tam();
int **t = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int *)); // No olvidarse del free luego!
dimensionar(tam, t);
```

y

```
void dimensionar (int tam, int **t1)
{
   *t1 = (int *)malloc(tam*sizeof(int));
}
```

Así, *t1* contiene la dirección de la variable *t*, y al hacer la indirección estás escribiendo el valor devuelto por el *malloc* en la variable *t* del *main*.

Pero es muy feo, complicado, y no te ayuda para nada (salvo que sea para enseñarte cómo funcionan las indirecciones y lo que se puede hacer con ellas); yo consultaría con tu profesor para asegurarme de que has entendido bien lo que quiere.